# How to fix rough opening of closet door

Tags: doors, interior, closet

I'm redoing our master bedroom closet and the original doors were 1970 type sliding doors. The rough opening is 65.5". All the bedrooms already had a face-lift with wheat oak bi-fold doors and I would like to stick to the same trim and bi-fold door look.

The problem I have is the opening in the master bedroom is too wide or too narrow for bi-fold doors of the style we have. We can either get 30" doors which leaves 2 inches to make up with 2x4's or something else. The 36" doors are too wide.

So my question is what can I do to make the 30" bi-fold doors work? The trim going around the doors are 2.25" wide which would not cover the 2" space I need to make up and at least 1/2" of the jamb.

Comment: Can you get us some photos of the situation to go with your measurements?

Comment: There are doors that are available in 32" and 34" wide leaves, They may be special order. I am surprised that 32" leaves are not readily in stock, usually only 34" wide doors are special order

Comment: $70 at Menards. A special order in the closest look is about $224 for each bi-fold. So instead of $140 for two bi-fold doors I would spend around $450. Home Depot has bi-fold doors in 32 inch but its not the same door.  

A picture wouldn't do any good. It's just a rough opening of 65.5 inches. 

I'm going to Menards today and I'll probably buy jamb extenders. So you wont see the door trim then the wall paint. It will be door trim, jamb extender then the paint.

Answer (score 2):

Either way you go here there's drywall and paint involved.

If it's not load bearing, just move the stud until you can fit the larger door. Barring miracles this will involve removed, replacement and refinishng of drywall.

If it's load bearing, add a stud on one side to make the new opening and drywall it in, since you can't cover it (or one on each side) with trim.